# XSLT nested formatting grouping

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT. I have a classic ASP page that fetches an xml file through a custom COM object. Here's the file structure:

the first row contains values related to the year (argument type="1"), following 12 rows containing monthly data (argument type="2"), and so on for x years.
The output I need to create is a HTML table with textbox elements where I can show/hide month records and make some client side validation based on user input vs xml data. The "year" rows (argument type="1") are always visible and contain the "+" sign in the first table cell to show/hide the month rows (argument type="2"). I've already created the show/hide and validation Javascript functions.

I need help with creating/formating the XSLT file. Eventually, I also need to convert the month number to a descriptive month name
Thanx

```
<row year="2016" type="1" euro="100000000.00"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="1"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="2"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="3"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="4"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="5"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="6"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="7" euro="1000234000.00"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="8"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="9"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="10"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="11"/>
<row year="2016" type="2" month="12"/>
<row year="2017" type="1" euro="199996993.00"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="1"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="2"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="3"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="4"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="5"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="6"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="7" euro="125000000.00"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="8"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="9"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="10"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="11"/>
<row year="2017" type="2" month="12"/>
```

Here's the code I'm using, not sure if it's the best way to go, but it seems like it's working so far

```
<xsl:for-each select="row">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@type='1'>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript:ToggleYear(<xsl:value-of select="@year"/>)</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">a_<xsl:value-of select="@year"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:text>+</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:if test="@type = 2">
        <xsl:element name="tr">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@year"/>_H_<xsl:value-of select="@month"/></xsl:attribute>

            <td><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Quite broad question I think, maybe you edit it showing the code that you have already.

Comment: Thanx Stefan, I've updated the code

Comment: Please show us the expected HTML output.

Comment: Also, please include root tag in XML. Very important especially if it uses namespaces.

Comment: no, I'm no t using namespaces. The xml documents has different nodes since it contains both input and output data. Is it used to send parameters to the Stored Procedure and also it contains the return data for the output

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: the above xslt is working, here's the html output I've created. I'll leave it this way for now.

P.S.
Now I have to create some client side JS validation to compare the output data and user input and send back the data via JS -> ASP -> XML -> COM -> SQL Server, but I already seem to got this working:)

[html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8trkT.png)